# How to prevent lombok from being packaged into Spring Boot jar?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

If you visit official [Lombok Maven guide](http://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo/), you will see that it's scope should be `provided`. 
When I create a new project from scratch using [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io/) and add Lombok, it gets only `<optional>true</optional>` in resulting pom.
Then I package Spring boot app like this and out of curiosity decide to see what gets packaged inside of jar:

> mvn clean package -DskipTests=true && unzip target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -d exploded

Lombok is packaged, does not matter if I set scope to `provided` or only have `optional=true`.

How to prevent Lombok from being included to Spring Boot jar?

My last thought was to try another goal which comes with Spring Boot plugin:

> mvn spring-boot:repackage

But unfortunately it produces the following error:

> repackage failed: Source file must be provided

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Lombok will only be available in a seperate folder lib-provided instead of the usual lib folder if you are packaging war file.

In order to exclude lombok completely from the final jar/war file, you have to do this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                </exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Please refer to Exclude a dependancy section of Spring Boot Maven Plugin https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/maven-plugin/reference/html/#repackage-example-exclude-dependency for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a transitive dependency of one of your dependency. If you  confirm it, you know what to do.

Comment: The `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` shows it's scope as `provided` and not as someone's else dependency. I afraid the problem is in Boot Maven plugin.

Comment: I clearly remember I saw lombok as compile dependency of one of the spring /boot modules... Don't think it as maven plugin issue. You can also check this by adding some other jar as provided dependency and then see if it's packaged or not.

Comment: Good idea. Just added `spark-core` as a `provided` dependency. As a result it gets also bundled with it's transitive jetty.